# How to modify and restore property of non static object

Tags: php

I have a class like the following :

```
 class page{

          public $head_html = array();


             ///...........

            public function head_html($input = ''){

                if(isset($input) && !in_array($input,$this->head_html))
                    return $this->head_html[] = $input;
                return implode("\n",$this->head_html);
            }

            ///...........

      }

    $page = new page();
```

It has been used in many pages and I don't want to make changes that affects other pages , so i can't make class static ,..

But I want to modify the global object instance in my pages :

```
$page->head_html("css code");
$page->head_html("js code");
```

And restore it like this :

```
echo $page->head_html();
```

But it shows nothing ..

when I try this :

```
echo implode("\n",$page->head_html);
```

It works fine , But in some cases it will be more complicated to get the value..
How can I achieve this using a function/method inside that class without changing the behavior of other pages and files that has used this class?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the true/false result of `$this->head_html[] = $input;` if you are not passing `head_html()` a value in the array. Is that what you want? If you want `head_html()` to return the updated value remove the `return` in

```
return $this->head_html[] = $input;
```

Comment: A single = is assignment, so it's just returning the result of the assignment.

Comment: @nigelren, that's what I am saying. He's getting a true/false rather than the updated value.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing the input default value to null , as simple as that , actually the first condition ( isset() ) was always true because isset returns true for empty string..